# C#: Debugging generic errors in the GDI+ interface?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, gdi+

How can I easily debug a generic error occurring in the GDI+ interface?

I'm trying to save a Bitmap file.
It's happening on the Bitmap.Save(...) call.

Code:

```
var imagePath = @"C:\test.bmp";

//File.Create(imagePath);

Bitmap b = new Bitmap(100, 100);

for (int pixelXCounter = 0; pixelXCounter < 100; pixelXCounter++)
{
    for (int pixelYCounter = 0; pixelYCounter < 100; pixelYCounter++)
    {
        b.SetPixel(pixelXCounter, pixelYCounter, System.Drawing.Color.Salmon);
    }
}

b.Save(imagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

---

UPDATE:

So here's some more information about the error I'm receiving (after I comment out File.Creat() call):

ExternalException occurred:
"
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
"

Exception object's ErrorCode: -2147467259

Comment: what is the generic error? Is there a hex error code to it?

Comment: You accidentally got it right, almost.  You added File.Create() to intentionally cause a sharing violation.  No need to diagnose that one, you know what caused it.  But it is an *excellent* way to generate a good exception for the 97% case when the lousy exception is raised and you can't find out why.  Append `.Close()` and you'll now get an excellent exception for the 97% trouble with *imagePath*.  The only remaining 3% are a full disk, everybody can discover this by themselves, and a coding bug that makes the Image object unreadable.  Like a Dispose() call on the storage for the image.

Answer (score 2):

What dose File.Create() do ?! It lock the file and your bitmap can't be saved on disk. remove it :

```
var imagePath = @"C:\test.bmp";

Bitmap b = new Bitmap(100, 100);

for (int pixelXCounter = 0; pixelXCounter < 100; pixelXCounter++) {
    for (int pixelYCounter = 0; pixelYCounter < 100; pixelYCounter++)
    {
        b.SetPixel(pixelXCounter, pixelYCounter, System.Drawing.Color.Salmon);
    } }

b.Save(imagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: He intentionally added it to make Save() fail, the snippet was meant to provide a repro for the exception.  What he wants to know is: "how do I know it is specifically a sharing violation that was the underlying cause".

Comment: @HansPassant If this is true, i'm sorry about trouble of understanding the question, it's not so clear.

Comment: So uh, at the expense of sounding like an idiot, I actually had the File.Create() intentionally in my code. The reasoning was, before I was doing that, I was still getting the generic GDI+ interface error. So I was assuming maybe my issue was that you can't call the Bitmap.Save() method until the file exists already. True that I am a creating a lock on the file by doing so though. When I get home I'll do more testing / try out your code sample and I'll try to report back more information about the error I receive, thanks. And thanks Hans for helping me sound less stupid ;)